# Using g++ to compile a C++ program that uses Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, g++, protoc

I'm trying to compile a c++ program that uses Tensorflow and I am having some issues.

The basic idea is to first use bazel to generate a dynamic-library .so file and pass that to g++. But it seems problems occur before even that stage - my program first includes a .h file in tensorflow

```
#include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"
```

I think I passed the correct argument to g++ since it does find the header file, but it's complaining

```
../../tools/tensorflow/bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/device_attributes.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is


#error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
```

When I opened the device_attributes.pb.h file, I see the error is produced here

`11 #if GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERSION < 3002000

 12 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is

 13 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update

 14 #error your headers.

 15 #endif

 16 #if 3002000 < GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_MIN_PROTOC_VERSION

 17 #error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is

 18 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please

 19 #error regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc.

 20 #endif`

At first I thought it was because the protoc on my machine is too old; then I tried modifying the PATH so that it finds a newer version (3.2.0) of protoc first, but the problem is still there; I even tried the same thing on a different machine without an older protoc and the problem still occurs.

I was wondering if anyone has experienced similar issue before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found the issue... It is because somewhere it includes a "google/protobuf/stubs/common.h" file, which it is supposed to use the one in the tensorflow package but somehow there must have been another file with the same name in my PATH, which is of a different version, and sets a different compiler variable.